# How to select components selected via SelectComponents?

Tags: image-processing

I have selected the components of a "reduced" (dilated, thinned) image, now I need to go back to the original image and find the coordinates of the components I have found.

My code currently does something like this (`thinnedImage` is the image dilated and thinned, so that is is basically the wireframe of the original image):

```
components = MorphologicalComponents[ColorNegate[thinnedImage]];
selected=SelectComponents[
  ColorNegate[thin], {"FilledCircularity", "Eccentricity", "Area", "Centroid"}, criteria];
```

At this point my code knows which are the components of my interest. How do I get the centroids (in image coordinates) of those components I have selected via `SelectComponents`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`ComponentMeasurements[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComponentMeasurements.html), in particular:

```
ComponentMeasurements[..., "Centroid"];
```

This will give you a list of the centroids in the form

```
{1 -> {x1, y1}, 2 -> {x2, y2}, ...}
```

**Update**
As pointed out by nikie in a comment,

> Also, `ComponentMeasurements` takes a 3rd parameter `crit`, that basically does the same as `SelectComponents` last parameter - so you don't need `SelectComponents` at all.

Comment: +1. Also, `ComponentMeasurements` takes a 3rd parameter `crit`, that basically does the same as `SelectComponents` last parameter - so you don't need `SelectComponents` at all.